# HttpListener Performance Optimization

Tags: vb.net, iis, httplistener

I'm using HttpListener as a simple http server. I've been benchmarking req/sec performance by having HttpListener return the string "OK" to each request - this has hit a limit at 16,000 requests per second. Based on the following code, is there anything that I can do to further optimize performance? Or are we hitting the limits of Windows Http.sys?

Image uploading isn't working, here's a link to the Visual Studio performance trace:

[VS Performance Trace](http://i52.tinypic.com/w0qg6d.jpg)

```
Public Class HTTPServer

    Shared Listener As HttpListener = New HttpListener

    Public Shared Sub Start()

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePoints = 500

        Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost/")
        Listener.Start()

        For i As Integer = 1 To (System.Environment.ProcessorCount * 2)

            Dim NewThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ListenerThread)
            NewThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
            NewThread.IsBackground = True
            NewThread.Start()

        Next

    End Sub



    Private Shared Sub ListenerThread()

        Dim SyncResult As IAsyncResult

        While True

            SyncResult = Listener.BeginGetContext(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ListenerCallback), Listener)
            SyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()

        End While

    End Sub



    Private Shared Sub ListenerCallback(ByVal StateObject As IAsyncResult)

        Dim Listener As HttpListener = DirectCast(StateObject.AsyncState, HttpListener)

        Dim Context As HttpListenerContext = Listener.EndGetContext(StateObject)
        Dim Request As HttpListenerRequest = Context.Request

        Dim Response As HttpListenerResponse = Context.Response

        Dim ResponseString As String = "OK"

        Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ResponseString)
        Response.ContentLength64 = Buffer.Length
        Dim OutputStream As System.IO.Stream = Response.OutputStream
        OutputStream.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)

        OutputStream.Close()
        OutputStream.Dispose()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Sorry me, how did you get 16K requests per second? I made tests with 300 parallel requests and got 30K requests per ~40 seconds. And made stress tests with Pylot with 1-500 agents and got ~250 requests per second. Please explain it;) All tests I made on the same machine (localhost). What I made wrong? Thank you!!!

Comment: P.S. From one thread (only one parallel thread) I made 16K requests and it was done by ~54 seconds; I don't understand:)))

Comment: now I got ~13-16K requests per 2-4 seconds))) My first tests were slow, as I understand, because of Increment lockings, tracing to files etc; I remove all of such "garbage":)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well *one* thing you can do is only call `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OK")` once, instead of on every request. I doubt that it'll make much difference, but if you're doing exactly the same thing on every request, you might as well have that response in the form you need it.

I would also use a `Using` statement rather than calling Close and Dispose explicitly. That's not a performance thing - just general good practice to avoid problems with unclosed streams when there are exceptions.

Realistically, do you *need* to hit more than 16K QPS? Have you worked out whether you're being CPU-bound or IO-bound? As soon as your program needs to actually do some real work on each request, I would imagine that will dwarf any micro-optimizations you make here anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Jon. I should have been clearer in my question - the "OK" string is for benchmarking this block of code only, this string will be dynamicly generated in production.

I'm serving objects from a hashtable out of memory - not much processing going on - so the http.sys overhead may be significant.

CPU is sitting at around 50% across four cores through this benchmark.

Comment: @Satellite: Right - so presumably generating that text dynamically will require some work... do you have any idea how much work that will be vs the work required simply to service the request? I would *expect* the vast majority of your time to go "real work" making the overhead from IIS mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Jon, sorry I posted my last commend prematurely - please see amendments.

Comment: @Satellite: Okay... so can you pre-serialize the objects, in the same way that I suggested pre-encoding the string? What sort of serialization are you using? That may well be taking more of the work than you think. How many QPS are you really serving, and are you sure that trying to scale up is more effective than trying to scale out?

Comment: The objects in memory are primarily strings, so I could pre-encode /some/ of them, however most do require that the timestamps are updated on each request. I'm using this a little like one might use memcached - as a middle tier in a web app serving multiple web servers. I dont expect memcached levels of performance, just trying to optimize what I can.

It sounds like I haven't committed any obvious performance 'no-no's with the code - that's really the answer I was searching for!

Comment: @Jon, sorry, please explain me, how get 16K requests per second in Satellite's http server? I made tests with 300 parallel requests and got 30K requests per ~40 seconds. And made stress tests with Pylot with 1 to 500 agents and get ~250 requests per second. From one thread (only one parallel thread) I made 16K requests and it was done by ~54 seconds; All tests I made on the same machine (localhost). So I did not got 16K requests per second))) What I made wrong? Thank you!!!

Comment: @Edward83: Well seeing as I can see neither your code nor Satellite's code, I'm not really the person to ask...

Comment: @Edward83 You should be able to get the code in the original question up and running without too much work. Make sure you are running parallel listener threads. I achieved those performance numbers on an Intel Quadcore @ 3.3GHz with 8 listener threads.